# Ubuntu 4K Monitor with GT 520

Tags: nvidia, display

I'm trying to get my Ubuntu (18.04) machine here running a 4K monitor in (near) 4K. Currently, the display is in 1080p. In fact, any resolution higher than 1080p is not even an option in the Settings:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVVXs.png

I've tried a couple things using xrandr, specifically [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/) website, in an attempt to add my own resolution option.

The specifications about this card (found [here](https://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-520/specifications)) say that the card supports a max resolution of 2560x1600. This is what I attempted to add using xrandr and that previous site, which resulted in the error:

```
sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 "2560x1600_60.00"
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  29
  Current serial number in output stream:  30
```

Any help getting a higher resolution would be appreciated! I don't care about FPS here, and I know I won't be able to achieve actual 4K, but I hope that 2560x1600 is actually possible.

PS: I've also tried updating drivers to no avail